# Surprising behavior of literal type at runtime

Tags: c++, clang, c++14

I'm a bit perplexed by the behavior of this code compiled with clang 3.9:

```
struct A {
    constexpr A() = default;
    A(const A&) = delete;
    constexpr A(A&&) {}
    A& operator =(const A&) = delete;
    constexpr A& operator =(A&&) { return *this; }
    constexpr operator bool() const { return &self == this; }
private:
    A& self{*this};
};

constexpr A fooA() { return {}; }    

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    static_assert(fooA(), "");
    return fooA();
}
```

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/g/CDFXAc

Static/compile-time evaluation is happening correctly for `fooA`; however at runtime the constructor seems to be omitted completely. The `static_assert` is not fired (as expected) but main still returns 0. Is that because `A` is a literal type or is it because of a compiler bug?

In case of the former any references to the standard would be appreciated.

Comment: GCC 6.3 on Godbolt fails this assertion.

Comment: @AnT yes, as does 7.0 but what does it prove?

Comment: @ildjarn do you want to elaborate which part is UB exactly?

Comment: Just a clang bug.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The problem is that the output depends on whether copy elision is performed or not (if not, `self` is initialized to a temporary so `fooA()` becomes non const and its declaration ill-formed, then you get the unexpected behavior. In the standard there's no strong requirement of copy elision in this context (for c++14) so you get different behaviors from different compilers. You can get more details of this problem in this [report](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#2022)

Comment: even if copy elision would happen copy ctor would still need to be available/visible, in my case its deleted

Comment: If copy elision happen the copy ctor is not needed, and then you have a well defined behavior, the problem happen when copy elision doesn't happen, you can check that in the assembler after compiling without optimizations (with a compiler with the problem). The solutions is to guarantee copy elision in constexpr context for construction, I know it was proposed for c++17 but I don't know if it went through

Comment: I was refering to : `When copy-elision takes place (until C++17)In those cases where copy-elision is not guaranteed, if it takes place (since C++17) and the copy-/move-constructor is not called, it must be present and accessible (as if no optimization happened at all), otherwise the program is ill-formed.`

Comment: exactly, that's since c++17, if copy-elision is not guaranteed and I takes place the copy ctor doesn't need to be visible in c++14. Just take a look at this [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/mmBFn8) you can see that in both cases the constructor is called but in the first case (fooA) self is initialized to a temporary and when bool() is called A is pointing to a different address

Comment: that is in my godblot link too, it was remove from question by someone 'for clarity'...

Comment: but in your godblot link you are compiling with O3 so the call to A::A() doesn't appear, if you compile without it you can see very clear that A::A() is called inside of `fooA()` (and not omitted as you mention in the question), `self` is initialized to some address and then the pointer to fooA() is moved before the call to `operator bool()`, so they end up pointing to different addresses. As the report 2022 says, if copy-elision doesn't happen, the initialization is non-const and then the declaration of constexpr fooA() is ill-formed. Is not a bug of the compiler is a problem in the standard.

Comment: But there's no copy to elide here.

Comment: A is constructed inside fooA and returned by value, that sounds like candidate for RVO to me

Answer (score 2):

Here's an even more reduced example:

```
struct A {
    constexpr A() : self(this) { }
    A* self;
};

int main() {
    constexpr A a{};
}
```

Neither gcc nor clang accept this code as they do not like the usage of `this` in the initializer. However, `this` is allowed in a constant expression as long as it's in a `constexpr` constructor, since [N3652](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html). MSVC gets this right.

Comment: In your case compilers dont like the code, in my question compiler DOES like it, its me who does not like what it produces :)

Comment: If your code fails to compile but OP's code does compile, then this is not a reduced example of OP's problem

Comment: @M.M It's the same problem - both compilers do the wrong thing with `this`, they happen to do different wrong things, and inconsistent wrong things, but it's the same root problem.

Comment: Also, gcc doesn't compile OP's code. Clang compiles it, but does contradictory things.

Comment: not the same problem, if you return `A{}` directly in the original code [link](https://godbolt.org/g/hQ4y3l) you get the expected behavior, the problem is `fooA`